# Intellisense not working for Xamarin Xaml Form in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: xamarin.forms

1. Intellisense is not working for Xamarin Xaml form in Visual Studio 2015 Community edition on Windows 10
2. Forms preview is not working.

Answer (score 1):

To open an XAML document with IntelliSense, right click on the XAML file and select open with.  Then select Automatic Editor Selector (XML).  You can also set it as the default.

The Microsoft IntelliSense used in the Automatic Editor Selector isn't the greatest, and if it doesn't work for you there are other third party options that you can pay for.

Comment: Also, when making a Xamarin.Forms project there is no preview.  This is because it is making it for Android, iOS, windows, etc. which each have different methods of displaying your code.  If you want to see an approximate preview, you could try using GorillaPlayer, which is a third party XAML previewer, although it has a few bugs. http://gorillaplayer.com/

Comment: Not totally true what you said about the XAML previewer. There's one already since last year, it's not the best one but it works: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/

Comment: I apologize, I never knew about the XAML previewer.  When I started it wasn't around so that's really exciting to hear!

Answer (score 0):

to quote mhutch from Xamarin,
"Note - if you right click on the file and "Open with->Source Code Editor" you should get XML completion", her answer from the [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/8010/#Comment_8010),

The Automatic Editor Selector doesn't open every xaml file I have, and I'm yet to find a rhyme or reason for that. But the "Source Code Editor" works for the files where XAML Intellisense doesn't automatically work.

As for the Previewer, I'm guessing you're already using Xamarins one ([XAML Previewer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/)), its not the smartest, so doesn't cope with anything too complex. I've used it successfully on Mac to mock up basic layouts. Currently my XAML files are causing the PC based Previewer grief, but its telling me the exception, so should be resolvable...apart from the exception window clipping the exceptions off at the end, but its a start.